# Apache Following Old Symbolic Link After Updating The Link

Tags: apache

I have apache pointing to a symbolic link for a website. I'm using capistrano to deploy the code so it updates the symbolic link to point to the new release

After capistrano updates the symbolic link to the new release directory apache uses the previous release directory.

The weird thing is it doesn't happen all the time. After a deploy everything either works fine or apache follows the previous link until i restart or reload apache.

any ideas?

Comment: Try this link: http://serverfault.com/questions/294107/apache-php-appears-to-be-caching-symbolic-links-for-60-seconds-how-to-stop-it

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on Apache httpd holding a handle on the old symlink. As long as that is the case the old data (symlink) is not thrown away in Unix based filesystems.

It seems you are unable to predict whether this is the case. Maybe use of lsof can help. What could also help is to trigger a graceful restart of httpd.